# Animation events firing on psuedo-elements?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, pseudo-element

I'm observing some inconsistent behaviour regarding animation events.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2J37a/

In Chrome, I'm seeing a `webkitAnimationIteration` event for each iteration of `fly` in addition to the `webkitAnimationIteration` event for each iteration of `rainbow`

Firefox is the same as Chrome, but obviously it fires `animationiteration` events instead of `webkitAnimationIteration`

IE, however, does not seem to be firing any events for the `fly` animation, only for the main element's `rainbow` animation.

Which behaviour is correct?

Additionally, in the case where both the main element and a psuedo-element are using the same animation (but maybe with different times or directions), how would I distinguish which one has fired in Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, it seems, I should RTFM before posting.

Specifically, [the specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-events).

From here, I find that:

- It is *correct* to fire events when the pseudo-element iterates an animation
- The event object has a `pseudoElement` property which can differentiate between the main element and its `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements. *Not supported in Chrome! Kind of important, guys, should probably implement that!*
- The correct spelling is "pseudo". Not "psuedo". The red squiggly line means a spelling error, Niet, pay attention already!